# How do I get the number of bytes read from StreamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync in WinRT/Metro Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store

I'm doing a byte read using StreamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync() in a WinRT/Metro app, and need to know how many bytes were actually read. This read is being treated as a **synchronous read** and **must stay a synchronous read.**

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
var receivedTask = this._socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), length, Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.None);
receivedTask.AsTask().Start();
receivedTask.AsTask().Wait(timeout);
// Need code here to get the number of bytes received

if (receivedBytes > 0)
{
    receivedTotal += receivedBytes;
    continue;
}
else
{
    // Socket Closed
}
```

Comment: You get them the same way you'd get them if you were to treat it as asynchronous: From the Task.Result property.

Comment: That returns an IBuffer. Would that not correspond to the buffer variable passed to the read? Or would it be new object? If it's a new object, then the actual received byte count would be the .Length property?

Comment: Indeed! The Task.Result.Length property will read the number of bytes returned from the ReadAsync! In fact, even when using the same buffer variable, the Length property only represents the amount of bytes read during the previous read! Thank you!

Comment: You *REALLY* don't want to ever use .Wait in a windows store app.  Instead use `result = await this._socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(...)`. Using .Wait blocks the UI thread and renders your application unresponsive.

Comment: I've read this before, but at the moment refactoring the library to not use .Wait() would be counter-productive. If I had written the library from the ground up, then I'd be all over it; however, I'm working with hand-converted standard .NET code, and I'm not quite familiar with everything the library yet.